# Redmine plugin not found

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm doing a installation on a Ubuntu machine (16.04 server) and I need to install the plugins for the Redmine platform (the lastest version). I installed Redmine using the official documentation: [Install Redmine step by step on Ubuntu](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step)

The installation was successful but now I have to install some plugins but every time I try to install I get: **plugin was not found**.

Since I made everything as said in the documentation I have this folder structure:

var/www/html/redmine

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  459 Mar 13  2016 404.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  648 Mar 13  2016 500.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  473 Mar 13  2016 dispatch.fcgi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7886 Mar 13  2016 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   43 Jul 13 12:07 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  143 Jul 13 12:07 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x 51 root root 4096 Jul 12 16:11 help
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jul 12 16:12 images
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jul 12 16:12 javascripts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 12 16:12 plugin_assets
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 Jul 19 17:30 plugins
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 Jul 19 18:37 public -> /usr/share/redmine/public
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Jul 13 10:02 redmine_agile
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 12 16:12 stylesheets
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jul 12 18:05 themes
```

To install the plugins I follow this tutorial: [Install plugin](https://www.redmineup.com/pages/help/checklists/installing-redmine-checklists-plugin-on-linux). I use this command: `bundle install --without development test --no-deployment` on /var/www/html and everything is ok. But then I need to use `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_checklists RAILS_ENV=production` (in the same location as the previous command) and I get plugin was not found

Things I already tried:

- Use Redmine last version
- update bundler
- execute rake on Redmine root
- update all gems
- set the right permissions on the plugins folders

and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

`bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`
 `NAME="YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME"` in the root_app folder